# Autoloader filter duplicates does not work

Tags: azure, pyspark, azure-databricks, autoload

I am loading the data from D365 crm via dataverse in azure data lake. I have configured the synapse link with `append only` functionality, which will keep the hisotrical data too.

Using the autoloader and reading the from adls with the below code.

```
df = (
    spark.readStream
    .option("delimiter", ",")
    .option("quote", '"')
    .option("mode", "permissive")
    .option("lineSep", "\r\n")
    .option("multiLine", "true")
    .format("cloudFiles")
    .option("cloudFiles.format", source_format)
    .option("cloudFiles.schemaLocation", checkpoint_directory)
    .option("header", "false")
    .option("escape", '"')
    .schema(schema)
    .load(data_source)
)
```

Next Im trying to do some transformation on `df` in order to keep only the uniqiue ID ( no duplications) based on latest `modifiedon` column.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import max
df = df.dropDuplicates()
df = df.withWatermark("modifiedon", "1 day")
agg = df.groupBy("id","modifiedon").agg(max("modifiedon").alias("max_modifiedon"))
agg = agg.select("id", "modifiedon")
final =df.join(agg, on=["id", "modifiedon"], how="inner")
```

and then trying to load into delta table (using azure databricks)

```
final.writeStream.format("delta").option("checkpointLocation", checkpoint_directory).trigger(availableNow=True).start("abfss://bronze@prd.dfs.core.windows.net/D365/msdyn_workorder_autoloader_nodups")
```

after querying the table I still can see the duplicated IDs and `max(modifedon)` is not picked.

Where am I making mistake here?

Comment: You need to do `groupby` only on `id` column, and then try to do display or write `agg`
dataframe.

Comment: When Im doing `groupby` only with `id` it has the problem of `writestream`. Please see this link here https://shorturl.at/izFZ4

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window` function and aggregate it.
Use below code.

```
df = df.dropDuplicates().withColumn("modifiedon",to_timestamp("modifiedon","dd/MM/yyyy")).withWatermark("modifiedon", "1 day")
agg = df.groupBy(window("modifiedon","10 day"),"id").agg(max("modifiedon").alias("modifiedon")).select("id","modifiedon")
final =df.join(agg, on=["id","modifiedon"], how="inner")
```

Here, I am using window on 10 days, and you use according to your streaming data.
I suggest you use more than 7-day window.

[image]

Output:

```
final.writeStream.format("delta").option("checkpointLocation", "/checkpoint_directory/").trigger(availableNow=True).start("/out_delta/")
spark.read.format("delta").load("/out_delta/").show()
```

[image]

Comment: I have to run pipeline in every 4h, as the data comes in every 15 min interval in lake. should I still use winodw of 10 days?

Comment: also, in your output why do you have duplicated ids? Im suppose to have unique ids

Comment: That is because i've given the dates with different year and done window on 10 days only, so it came like that. If your date within a year you give window as 365 days.

Comment: That is not clear in my situation, as some records can be updated which was created in 2019 or even later so this wont work for me. Plus Im going to use `foreachbach` and `merge into` to upsert the data in delta lake

Comment: At the end you need latest of the date with same id right?. Then it is obvious that previous record will get updated.

Comment: yes, I need max `modifiedon` with the corresponding id to mergeinto deltatable. Please see here, i posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76866553/append-output-mode-not-supported-when-there-are-streaming-aggregations

Comment: yeah. even i faced same issue with giving only `id` in groupby. so i added window function with interval depends on your data.
If you have dates within a month and you want latest date you need to add 30 days interval in window which takes `max` on that 30 days interval dates,similarly if dates range is 3-4 years than need to give those range in intervals `3*365` or `4*365` which takes `max` on those intervals.

Comment: problem is that I dont know the date range

Comment: Are you getting unique id in agg itself? If yes, why do you need join?

Comment: well in agg, I get only `id` and `modifedon` and I dont have anyother columns so Im joining to get the rest of the data in my df

Comment: if I use the `outputMode("complete")` it failes due to my join, but I cant think of other ways to not use the join so I can use it.

Comment: All you need is range of your date. Get max date and min date and try checking range.

Comment: `display(df.select(add_months(max("modifiedon"),12).alias("maxi"),min("modifiedon").alias("mini")).withColumn("range",datediff(end=col("maxi"),start=col("mini"))))`
Try this and see the range.

Comment: I already tried to get the range but `df.select` does not work with streaming source. see the error: `Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();`

Comment: what about `writestream.format("console").start()` and see output in cluster stdout logs.